# Error in shell script: Integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell

i am studying shell script right now. I started to learn how to work with more complex if statements. What's wrong with this code bellow? I read other similar questions here in stackoverflow, but i couldnt resolve my problem. Now im verifying if the first, second or third argument is null. In the future i pretend to verify based in some regex or something like that.
Thanks!!

The code (line 9):

```
if [ "$1" -eq "" ] || [ "$2" -eq "" ] || [ "$3" -eq "" ] then ...
```

> line 9: [: : integer expression expected
>  line 9: [: : integer
>   expression expected
>  line 9: [: : integer expression expected

Answer (score 2):

`-eq` performs an arithmetic comparison between two numbers. Use `=` for string comparisons. Or better yet, use `[[` and `==`.

```
[[ $1 == "" ]]
[ "$1" = "" ]
```

You can also use `-z` and `-n` to directly test whether a value is empty/non-empty.

```
[[ -n $value ]]    # [[ $value != "" ]]
[[ -z $value ]]    # [[ $value == "" ]]
```

Answer (score -1):

use `[[` and `]]` for the more modern / complex operators. This is a bashism, so beware.